# Iframe to send an event to it's parent?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have 2 sites which i own, that does the following:

i have one site that puts an iframe from site 2 (both of the are angular apps).

<-- site one html -->

```
<iframe src='site2.com'></iframe>
```

<-- site two -->

```
 <button ng-click='someEventToParent(event)'> </button>
```

I want to put a button in site 2 (This is the site from the iframe) and when i press it, it closes the iframe on site 1.

How should i achieve this? can i send an event to the parent site? If so, what kind of event should i send to the site.

Comment: You can't really send an event, but you can call a function in the parent page by doing `window.parent.functionName()`. How you'd do that with the abomination that is Angular, I don't know ?

Comment: Come on guys, anyone have a good idea how to handle this one?

Comment: using postMessages? http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

Comment: How can i get the full path of the parent window of the iframe...if i use this: console.log(document.referrer); i get only the referer without the params, can i get all the url?